# How to reference a picture from a website in a report?

Tags: citations, graphics, website

Let's say that I have taken this picture in this webpage

https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Ultrasonics/js_apps/transducerBeamSpread/

If I did change some things in that picture , How can I now make the reference of that picture in my report? Can you please write to me how the reference will be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just caption it as "credit: www.nde-ed.org (with original amendments)" and then drop the link into a footnote.